# Calling main activity method from another class

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

So I'm writing this app that will basically send a bluetooth message to another device when I receive an SMS. To send the bluetooth message, I use the Bluetooth sample chat app found here: [main source file](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChat.html). In terms of getting the SMS, I follow [this example](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android).

Basically in order to receive an SMS I register a BroadcastReceiver.

For the Bluetooth chat, there is a private BluetoothChatService which is initialized and set up when the app starts. That object is used in the function that writes through Bluetooth.

Now the problem is that I'm not too sure how to access either the object or the write method. Also I'm pretty sure I explained my set up right, so please double check the links I posted just to make sure I've explained it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a main activity method from another class you need a reference to this activity in that class, or you need a handler (callback). You can either go with the `Handler` defined in main activity, and when you want to invoke some code, send a message to this handler (like the Bluetooth sample you provide works).